# creat eventHandler for label array element

Tags: c#, label

I was wondering how am I supposed to assign an eventHandler for each array element in my label array. I understand that it's not possible to create a method for each of eventHandlers, so what could be the solution? Thank you!

```
for(int i = 0, i < 10; i++)
{
    lbs[i] = new Label();
    lbs[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76 + f, 164);
    lbs[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 17);
    //able to perform this, but wont able to create a method for this
    lbs[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(lbs[i]_Click);
}

//can't do this, what is alternative?
public void lbs[i]_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: On each of the label (when clicked), what would you want to do in the code?

Comment: Say, I would like to store some text

Comment: @Jack, do you want all the label clicks to cause the same action, or should they behave differently?

Comment: @codesparkle, actually i dont know yet. thanks to Nacereddine I know what to do if the action is same, but I have no clue what to do if the actions are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function name is invalid (you can't have `[]` in a function name) try changing `lbs[i]_Click` to `lbs_Click`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lbs[i] = new Label();
    lbs[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76 + f, 164);
    lbs[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 17);
    lbs[i].Name = "label" + i;

    //able to perform this, but wont able to create a method for this
    lbs[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(lbsi_Click);
}

public void lbsi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = sender as Label;
    if(label != null && label.Name == "label1"){
        //event was raised from label1
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this method know then which label number is clicked? I mean,I would have to create 10 same methods, how would it know which one is which for?

Comment: That's what the `sender` parameter is for.